# Проблема с адаптацией на телефоне wordpress visual composer

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, visual-composer

Появилась проблема с адаптацией на телефонах, страница загружается обычно, все как надо, но стоит лишь свайпнуть влево и весь сайт идет боком. Помогите пожалуйста!

Не на всех страницах есть такая проблема.

www.bodyfitness.ee

Comment: https://ibb.co/x3TyJSm

Скриншот закинул сюда, так как на телефоне не дает возможность загрузить фотографию, кнопка не работает.

Comment: Нет такой проблемы

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае проблема на странице "О магазине" где видно что плагин не подгружает все стили, поэтому мы видим это прямо на странице:

[vc_row][vc_column width=”1/1″] и т.д.

А точнее не подгружаются стили ассетов

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="vcv:assets:source:main:styles:assets-bundles35b4e7aedfc766ee59198eeacbac3564sourcecss-css" href="http://bodyfitness.ee/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/visualcomposer-assets/assets-bundles/35b4e7aedfc766ee59198eeacbac3564.source.css?ver=23.0.35b4e7aedfc766ee59198eeacbac3564" type="text/css" media="all">
```